# CSS does not update with Django

Tags: html, css, django

When I modify the CSS file and then run `python manage.py collectstatic`, (typing in `yes` if prompted) and then reload the website on the localhost, I expect the CSS to be changed.  Instead, it is not.  What are some possible causes and solutions?

Edit:  I have been calling this with `collectstatic` as intended, as opposed to the typo that was previously in the question.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: do you use `manage.py runserver' with `DEBUG=True` in the `settings.py`? or is the problem in the deployment level using WAS like Apache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i had to clear cache to get it to update if i haven't changed it for a while. after an initial purge, it usually updates on a change.

also, as i'm using chrome, i just remove it for the last hour so it doesn't affect too many things.

Comment: Clearing the chrome cache seems incredibly silly, but that's what worked!

Comment: i know, right!? just found out from a colleague that `ctrl+F5` forces a cache refresh; that's going to be handy!

Comment: ctrl + shift + r or cmd + shift + r for chrome works for me!

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in you command; `collectstatic` is one word.

The command should be:

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

Also, you should setup the `STATIC_URL`, `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your `settings.py` file with the proper values.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your command is wrong. Please try this

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

You can refer here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

Beware of editing the wrong css file. I made the mistake of editing the one located in the "static_cdn" directory rather than the one in "static". After running collectstatic, do clear the browser cache as a few have suggested above.